# Can clients on Office 2010 Pro use SP2013 to edit in browser?

Tags: 2013, office-integration, office-web-apps

Has anyone successfully used an Office 2010 Pro Plus / Volume License (and possibly Standard) client to edit their Office 2010 docs within the browser on an on-premise SP2013 site (Foundation but hopefully same for Server)? Or does SP2013 Office Web Apps only accept Office 2013 clients (sound of sinking ship)?

Have to ask because couldn't find confirmation yet on otherwise good details at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219456.aspx. And it turns out you now need (not like SP2010) a whole new server just for OWA 2013 - ie. can't be on the SP WFE, or even the seperate SQL Server, when the V host is already squeezed thanks the the 8GB need from Search.

Would like to know from a real admin who is running an SP2013 but the elephant in the room is that their users are mostly on Office 2010 (or even, gasp, 2007 - as Office 2003 is a definate no-no).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office Web Applications does not require Office to be installed on the client machines (that's the point).

As far as licensing, an Office 2010 license would not cover an Office Web App 2013 license.  If you have SA or other upgrade rights, your Office 2010 licenses could be upgraded to 2013.  I would contact your sales channel for more specific details on your licensing.

Comment: Thanks John, and yes - good reality check, it sounds obvious and your answer to the title question is clearly “no” (which further licencing enquiries do confirm) although really wanted to know what actually happens under the circumstance stated?  SP2010 with Office 2003 clients under Forms Based Auth gave them an ugly blank login page to confuse them. Does SP2013 allow viewing (or not) and lock editing, or tell them they are not licenced etc? Any further clarification of user behaviour appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431682.aspx#license

I did test installing and editing documents with office 2010 standard and it worked fine.  The above link states that you have to have an office 2013 license to enable editing, so we disabled it.
If you find out anything different, let us know.